# transform ESRI:102008 polygon shapefile to EPSG:4326 via shapely

Tags: python, gis, transform, shapely, pyproj

I'm having trouble transforming a multipolygon shapefile with CRS of ESRI:102008 to EPSG:4326. The shapefile looks like this (data1) [image]

As I have difficulty merging ESRI shapefile with my other shape files with EPSG CRS, I'm trying to converting data1 into EPSG:4326, I followed the shapely transform documentation:

```
import pyproj
from shapely.ops import transform
from pyproj import Transformer

project = pyproj.Transformer.from_proj(pyproj.Proj('ESRI:102008'), pyproj.Proj('EPSG:4326'), always_xy=True)

data_transform = transform(project.transform, data1)
```

This is the error I got:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

What did I do wrong here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: what does your data1 holds? it should be only geometry